# Uploading an image file to database

Tags: python, html, django

I am making a social media app and i am adding a edit profile function to it. But for some reason, the profile image which the user chooses is not being uploaded to the database. Please help me to do so.

**My views.py**

```
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    user_profile = profile.objects.get(user__username=user)
    Profile = user_profile
    myuser = User.objects.get(username=user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            username = request.POST['username']
            name = request.POST['name']
            email = request.POST['email']
            image = request.FILES['img']

            myuser.username = username
            myuser.first_name = name
            myuser.email = email
            myuser.save()
            Profile.user = myuser.username
            Profile.name = myuser.first_name
            Profile.img = image
            Profile.save()

            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return redirect('/')

    else:
        context = {
            'user':user_profile,
            'myuser':myuser,
        }
        return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', context)
```

**my tempateview**

```
<form action="/users/edit_profile/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}

<center>
<img src="{{user.img.url}}" style="border-radius: 50%; widows: 150px;height:150px; margin-left:-50px" onclick="document.getElementById('image').click()"><br>

<span class="click" onclick="document.getElementById('image').click()">Change Profile Picture</span>
</center>
<input type="file" name="img" id="image" accept="image/*" style="display:none"><br><br>

<label> &nbsp;Username </label><br>
<input type="text" name="username" class="edit" value="{{user.user}}" spellcheck="false"><br><br>

<label> &nbsp;Name </label><br>
<input type="text" name="name" class="edit" value="{{user.name}}" spellcheck="false"><br><br>

<label> &nbsp;Email </label><br>
<input type="email" name="email" class="edit" value="{{myuser.email}}" spellcheck="false"><br><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Save changes" style="width:40%; float:right; margin-right:120px">

</form>
```

**my models.py**

```
class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Profile({})".format(self.user.username)
```

Everything is working. Only the image file cannot be uploaded. Please help. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: please post your models too

Comment: @arjun i have uploaded my models.py. you can check it

Answer (score 0):

this was a problem for me too. i solved this by saving the object like so:

```
 from django.core.files import File 
 Profile.img.save(image.name  , File(image))
 Profile.save()
```

hope it helped you.

Comment: is it raises an error? or is `image = request.FILES['img']`  a file object ? also check your admin --> profile objects.does the new object has been created? if it does , does it have a url in its field?

Comment: i am not creating a new object. I am editting an object which already exists.